# How do I receive live data from a long lived HTTP connection in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, http-streaming

I'm looking to process the results of a [long-lived HTTP connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#HTTP_server_push) from a server I am integrating with **as they happen**.  This server returns one line of JSON (`\n` delimited) per "event" I wish to process.

Given an instance of `Stream` assigned to the variable `changeStream` that represents bytes from the open HTTP connection, here's an extracted example of what I'm doing:

*(`request` is an instance of `WebRequest`, configured to open a connection to the server I am integrating with.)*

```cs
var response = request.GetResponse();
var changeStream = response.GetResponseStream();

var lineByLine = Observable.Using(
    () => new StreamReader(changeStream),
    (streamReader) => streamReader.ReadLineAsync().ToObservable()
);

lineByLine.Subscribe((string line) =>
{
    System.Console.WriteLine($"JSON! ---------=> {line}");
});
```

Using the code above, what ends up happening is I receive the first line that the server sends, but then none after that.  Neither ones from the initial response, nor new ones generated by real time activity.

- For the purposes of my question, assume this connection will remain open indefinitely.
- How do I go about having system.reactive trigger a callback for each line as I encounter them?

> Please note: This scenario is not a candidate for switching to SignalR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though this looks more complicated, it is better to use the built-in operators to make this work.

```
IObservable<string> query =
    Observable
        .FromAsync(() => request.GetResponseAsync())
        .SelectMany(
            r => Observable.Using(
                () => r,
                r2 => Observable.Using(
                    () => r2.GetResponseStream(),
                    rs => Observable.Using(
                        () => new StreamReader(rs),
                        sr =>
                            Observable
                                .Defer(() => Observable.Start(() => sr.ReadLine()))
                                .Repeat()
                                .TakeWhile(w => w != null)))));
```

It's untested, but it should be close.

Comment: Ooh, I like this.  I'll likely remove the `null` cancel as that's not necessary for my scenario.

How could I handle reconnects if the connection ever drops?

Comment: @AlexanderTrauzzi - You'd need to include the code that does the connection and gets the request. It's just the same as above - just more nesting. Then you can wrap that in a `.Defer` and end with a `.Retry`.

Comment: Also, removing the `.TakeWhile(w => w != null)` means that this observable would never naturally end. You'd have to make sure you dispose of any subscriptions manually.

Comment: If the disconnection is noticed by an exception when trying to read, is there any special handling needed?

Comment: What I'm noticing now is that when I do get null, it goes into an infinite loop of reading that same null.  How would I have it call `sr.DiscardBufferedData()` on `null` and then continuing to read?

Comment: @AlexanderTrauzzi - That's what the `.Defer` and `.Retry` to - basically bypass exceptions.

Comment: @AlexanderTrauzzi - To call `sr.DiscardBufferedData()` you could put a `.Finally` call after the `TakeWhile`.

Comment: Okay, so final question -- how do I get access to the `StreamReader` in a `Finally()`? All my `Catches` and `Finallys` only end up receiving a `string`.

Comment: @AlexanderTrauzzi - The `.Finally` would be immediately after the `.TakeWhile(w => w != null)`. That's where the `sr` is still in scope.

Comment: @AlexanderTrauzzi - Yes, but the `sr` is still in scope there too from the outer level.

Comment: Right!  Thank you :)

Comment: Take a look at let me know what you think! -- https://gist.github.com/atrauzzi/9259f20ea8b97b22c540caf1d0eb4b9a

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210407/discussion-between-enigmativity-and-alexander-trauzzi).

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt will only observe a single `ReadLineAsync` call. Instead you need to return each line. Probably something like this;

```cs
Observable.Create<string>(async o => {
    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    var changeStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    using var streamReader = new StreamReader(changeStream);
    while (true)
    {
        var line = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
        if (line == null)
            break;
        o.OnNext(line);
    }
    o.OnCompleted();
});
```

Comment: Is there any way this can be adapted to support fetching lines indefinitely? The connection is long lived and will be adding lines over time.

Comment: So long as the server is using chunked encoding, that should be fine. You should probably add some form of retry / reconnect handling to the loop as well...

Comment: There's a whole bunch of `IDisposable`s here are aren't being disposed. It looks like a fairly simple solution, but it's faulty because of two things - you need to dispose - and the observable completes synchronously with the subscription.